# Есть ли области где многопоточность лучше, чем асинхронность в python?

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio, асинхронность, threading

В python есть 3 способа выполнять код одновременно:

- многопроцессорность
- многопоточность
- асинхронность

Если с многопроцессорностью всё понятно - она позволяет реально распараллелить задачу, то насчет многопоточности и асинхронности возникают вопросы.
По факту из-за GIL все потоки на самом деле работают в одном потоке (прямо как корутины!!).
Они могут дать выигрышь в производительности только если в коде есть много неблокирующих операций (прямо как корутины!!!!).
Исходя из этого факта, возникает резонный вопрос: "Зачем вообще использовать потоки, если есть asyncio с корутинами?". О реализациях python без GIL слышал, но интересует стандартный python 3 (И о будущей реализации python без GIL тоже слышал).

Comment: А, понятно, я скорее всего ваш вопрос видел, а обсуждение в похожем вопросе было.

Comment: Если вычисления идут внутри сишных библиотек, которые отпускают GIL, то GIL для многопоточности перестаёт быть проблемой

Comment: Добавьте это в ответ. Я зачту вам, как правильный.

Comment: @andreymal  Добавьте это в ответ пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, что называть пакет **asyncio** "асинхронностью" не вполне корректно, поскольку и **multiprocessing**, и **threading**, и **asyncio** представляют собой три различных способа (возможности, метода) написания **асинхронного** кода. Подробнее здесь: https://youtu.be/0E50FVd5PGQ

Это с одной стороны. С другой стороны, само использование пекета **asyncio** отнюдь не гарантирует, что код в результате получится не **синх**ронным, а **асинх**ронным. Тут, как говорится, "всё дело в мастерстве мастера")))

Что же касается сути вопроса, то **threading** лучше **asyncio**, по крайней мере, в трёх случаях:

1.) Если в коде, который нужно сделать асинхронным, приходится использовать объект, не обладающий свойством ***awaitable*** (например пакет **requests** "не awaitable", поэтому в **asyncio** используется его  "awaitable" вариант - пакет **aiohttp**);

2.) Использование **asyncio** подразумевает существенное изменение исходного кода (в отличии от **threading**). Поэтому, если нет желания или возможности изменять исходный код, то асинхронность даст только **threading**;

3.) Ну и, наконец, изучение **asyncio** требует чуть больше времени. Поэтому, если задачу надо решать срочно, а вы не знаете ни того, ни другого, то научиться работать с потоками будет несколько проще и быстрее.

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на неточность в формулировании вопроса. Но всё же вопрос заключался в том, где threading эффективнее использовать с точки зрения производительности. Так как из-за GIL threading не даёт явных ощутимых преимуществ.